# How to make my extension send data to me?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension that will allow the user to rate the page they are viewing. To do this, I want to capture their click ('Good' or 'Bad') from the extension popup and also the url of the site they are visiting.

I can capture both these data in JavaScript, but how do I immediately extract this data to my computer? Is there a way to use JS to capture these values in a bucket and load them to an existing XLS file on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is have your extension make an AJAX request from the extension to your server. You'll need to ask for permission to allow the extension to access your server in the manifest.json file, as described in http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/manifest.html#permissions

Once you receive the request on your server, you can do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. I tried the AJAX request but it still doesn't let me create files on my local machine. Is this a security issue that I need to disable or is there a code to work around this problem?

Comment: You want to write the Excel file on your server, don't you? Not on the client which is running Chrome + your extension? If the former, then Chrome and your extension code are not involved with writing the Excel file at all; it is your server-side code.